# Filtering in Silverstripe GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter

Tags: silverstripe

Is it possible to add a filter to `GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter` similar `setFilterFunction` on `TreeDropdownField`?

```
TreeDropdownField::create(
    "LinkID",
    "Link to",
    "SiteTree"
)->setFilterFunction(create_function( '$obj', 'return $obj->isPublished();' ));
```

This would give a list of `SiteTree` objects that return true when `isPublished` is called.

Is there a way to filter the GridField autocompleter in a similar way?

In the following code `$this->Pages()` is a `has_many` relationship for `Page`. The result will just list all of the `Page` objects in the autocomplete dropdown.

```
GridField::create(
    'Pages',
    'Pages belonging to group',
    $this->Pages(),
    $config = GridFieldConfig::create()->addComponents(
        new GridFieldButtonRow('toolbar-header-right'),
        new GridFieldToolbarHeader(),
        new GridFieldSortableHeader(),
        new GridFieldFilterHeader(),
        new GridFieldDataColumns(),
        new GridFieldDeleteAction(true),
        new GridFieldDetailForm(),
        new GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter('toolbar-header-right')
    )
)
```

Is there a way it can be filtered?

Note: I want to filter by some other checks not just `isPublished`, I'm checking if the page's parent ID is the same as another relationship's ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a method called `setSearchList()` on `GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter` with which you can set the list to be searched.

however, I am not sure if that is fully implemented, but you should try the following:

```
// lets assume you want all Pages that have no parent (root pages)
$listToBeSearched = Page::get()->filter('ParentID', 0);
$autoCompleteField = new GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter('toolbar-header-right');
$autoCompleteField->setSearchList($listToBeSearched);
$config = GridFieldConfig::create()->addComponents(
    new GridFieldButtonRow('toolbar-header-right'),
    new GridFieldToolbarHeader(),
    new GridFieldSortableHeader(),
    new GridFieldFilterHeader(),
    new GridFieldDataColumns(),
    new GridFieldDeleteAction(true),
    new GridFieldDetailForm(),
    $autoCompleteField
);
```

if you wish to filter by a function like in your question, then use `filterByCallback()` to filter the list:

```
// because GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter only supports DataList at the moment 
// and filterByCallback() returns an ArrayList, we have to use a workaround 
// (which obviously yields a performance loss)
$arrayList = Page::get()->filterByCallback(function($obj) { return $obj->isPublished(); });

// now that we have a list of pages that we want to search, 
// lets take the IDs of this list and create a DataList that filters for this IDs:
$listToBeSearched = Page::get()->filter('ID', $arrayList->column('ID'));
```

Comment: Was trying this but was doing `$this->Page()` instead of `Page::get()`! Got it working now, thanks!

Comment: can you paste the full stacktrace (on some paste site or so)?

Comment: nvm, I know why this is the case, the problem is that `filterByCallback` returns a `ArrayList`. but `GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter` only works with `DataList` because it uses some features that are not supported by `ArrayList`

Comment: updated the answer, this hack/workaround should do the trick (however it is not efficient in terms of performance because all pages have to be fetched and then the selected ones have to be re-fetched again)

Comment: Thats the one! Performance isn't an issue for me in this case so that's fine. For the record though would storing the original Page::get() in a variable (`$Pages`) and then doing something like this http://pastebin.com/xqx9xxdF be better performance wise (unless column is an ArrayList only thing)?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think the cache is global, so this probably does not matter. however looking at your code, I see a way to dramatically (if you have a huge sitetree, small sitetree is fast anyway) improve performance: filter for $owner->ID at the beginning, this way you reduce the list of items to be filterd by the callback: http://pastebin.com/4Qh7Pj2r